# Magento Search returning no results

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch, search

I have a strange problem that I have spent hours trying to fix. For some reason the catalog search returns no results even though products are enabled and visible on the frontend.

I'm using

`https://github.com/fheyer/sphinxsearch`

which works fine on my dev box but on the live site it doesn't work and I'm running out of ideas on how to fix it.

It seems to be a common problem but none of the solutions that I have found seem to work.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. re-indexed from shell
2. cleared cache by deleting the var/cache folder
3. did a diff to see if any files are missing between development and live site
4. reinstalled the module
5. disabled the module

None of the above worked and I still can't search on the site, if anyone has come across this issue before I'd be grateful for some assistance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

1. Remove Sphinx search module
2. Clear Cache AGAIN
3. Reindex AGAIN

Search now working and I can go to bed.